# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Sounds in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

(before continuing I'd like to say that I develop on Mac OSX under VMWare, so if someone knows if it could be a VM problem please answer anyway regarding that)

I'm following a simple tutorial of cocos2d and I arrived to the sounds

This is the code I use for audio

Imports:

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Init method:

```
-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
if( (self=[super init]) )
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"Field1.mp3" loop:YES];

    CCMenuItemImage *uno = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"vblue.png" selectedImage:@"vblue.png" target:self selector:@selector(uno)];
    uno.position = ccp(-150,0);
    CCMenuItemImage *due = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"vgreen.png" selectedImage:@"vgreen.png" target:self selector:@selector(uno)];
   due.position = ccp(-50,0);

    CCMenuItemImage *start = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"play.png" selectedImage:@"play.png" target:self selector:@selector(uno)];
    start.position = ccp(150,0);
    CCMenuItemImage *stop = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"pausa.png" selectedImage:@"pausa.png" target:self selector:@selector(uno)];
    stop.position = ccp(50,0);

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:uno,due,start,stop, nil];
    [self addChild:menu];

}
return self;
}
```

The problematic line is

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"Field1.mp3" loop:YES];
```

Since Xcode reports of an audio error and without that line the game works.

Compiler Output:

```
<AudioControl> Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
2013-03-01 12:29:09.101 Tutorial10[374:4803]  

<AudioControl> Error getting audio     input device sample rate: '!obj'2013-03-01 12:29:09.102   Tutorial10[374:4803]  

<AudioControl> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2013-03-01 12:29:09.104 Tutorial10[374:1b03] 
<0xb0115000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
(lldb)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried this on an actual device, or only the simulator? Can you play other sounds without problems?

Comment: On both and I get the same problem. I don't know where I went wrong because in the tutorial I watched the guy does the same..

Comment: Have you tried a different MP3 (preferably one that's confirmed to work, ie from another game's app bundle)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with .mp3 and .wav, it crashes anyway. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging, I saw someone else with this same issue. Their problem was that they did not have a audio driver installed on their system, and therefore no sound was playing at all, and they were receiving that same error that you have.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13970

Would be strange if this also happens on an actual device though. What device are you testing on becides your PC?

Comment: The problem could be thid, I have also VMWare Tools installed but it seems strange that audio driver is not installed. I'll make some try and text you back. If you know other possible infos on this issue please text me back soon.